# SQL: find one to many in one table

Tags: sql

there is a table:
t1

```
Id | Acc Status| Acc Type| 
-----------------------------------------
1  |Online     | home
2  |Offine     | work
3  |Declined   | work
1  |Activated  | home
```

.

Question is:
need to find all Id which has 'Acc Status' = Online AND 'Acc Status' = Activated

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query -

```
SELECT id
FROM T1
WHERE AccStatus IN ('Online', 'Activated')
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT AccStatus) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must `group by id` and count the distinct values of `accstatus`:

```
select id 
from t1
where accstatus in ('Online', 'Activated')
group by id
having count(distinct accstatus) = 2
```

If you need the ids that have only these `accstatus` values:

```
select id 
from t1
group by id
having
  count(distinct accstatus) = 2
  and 
  sum(case when accstatus not in ('Online', 'Activated') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below query

```
SELECT id
FROM Table_name
WHERE AccStatus = 'Online' 
and id IN (SELECT id FROM Table_name wHERE AccStatus = 'Activated')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select DiSTINCT Id
from t1
where [Acc Status] in ("Online", "Activated")
```